# query to make result ordering match a given WHERE IN(a,b,c) condition

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

I am doing some works to fill in document by using MySQL Database. What I want to do is to make result with given WHERE condition. Following student table:

```
                  student
+-----+------------+-----------------+-----+
| id  |  nickname  |   student_name  | ... |
+-----+------------+-----------------+-----+
|  1  |     Joy    |     Anderson    | ... |
|  2  |    Prank   |     Campbell    | ... |
+-----+------------+-----------------+-----+
```

I gave this following query to database:

```
SELECT nickname FROM students WHERE student_name in ('Anderson', 'Campbell')
```

then, I expected a result like this:

```
Joy
Prank
```

Above expected result is matched with sequence on WHERE condition. ( WHERE student_name in ('Anderson', 'Campbell') ) Joy is matched with Anderson and Prank is matched with Campbell. But current result is like this:

```
Prank
Joy
```

Now, I don't know what I should do to make my expected result. Does anyone can give me some idea or information for this situation ?

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD(...)`

Comment: whats wrong with current result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fallen into a common SQL trap.  Rows such as your rows in `students` and members of sets such as  `('Anderson', 'Campbell')` **have no built-in order.**  The server doesn't know *anything* about `Anderson` coming before `Campbell` even though your query shows them that way.

Your only recourse is to use an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, results are shown in an order that's formally unpredictable. In your case `ORDER BY student_name` at the end of your query will make your row ordering predictable.

*Unpredictable* is a complex idea. It's like *random* except worse. *Random* usually implies a result is likely to be different each time. *Unpredictable* means it's the same every time, *until it isn't.*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! +1